# Keeping bytes in the SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, arrays

How can I keep a byte array in a SQL Server database?

I've tried putting it in a `NVARCHAR`, but it keeps the bytes as a string while I need to keep them as integers.

Is there a "Byte" type I can use?

Answer (score 4):

[`varbinary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362.aspx)